# Selecting an element with jQuery in a Twitter Bootstrap Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm placing the following content in a Twitter Bootstrap popover, which contains a link for which I want to listen for clicks:

```
<div id="popover-content">
  <a id="link" href="#">click</a>
</div>
```

I'm using a button to reveal the popover which contains the above content:

```
<button id="trigger" data-placement="bottom" title="title">Reveal popover</button>
```

I then associate the button with the popover and use jQuery's `click()` function in attempt to listen for clicks on the link contained in the popover:

```
$(function(){
  $('#trigger').popover({ 
    html: true,
    content: function() {
      return $('#popover-content').html();
    }
  }); 

  $('#link').click(function() {
    alert('beep');
  });
});
```

However, upon clicking the button to reveal the popover and then clicking the link, the click seems to not be detected as intended above. My understanding of the DOM and javascript and jQuery is fairly limited, so I'm not sure what's going on here. How can you select/listen for actions on elements contained in a popover?

Reference: [Popovers in Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to perform Event delegation here.Instead use `$('#popover-content')` instead of `$('#popover-content').html()` while setting the content. This will have the events registered attached by default without requiring any delegation.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G2Ddv/)

```
$(function(){
  $('#trigger').popover({ 
    html: true,
    content: function() {
      return $('#popover-content'); //<-- Remove .html()
    }
  }); 

  $('#link').click(function() {
    alert('beep');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. There must be something else going on with my actual implementation, as the popover contained no content when I tried this suggestion. I'll see what I can find out, as I would prefer this.

Comment: Yes do not use Event delegation when it s not exactly required. Let me know if it works? Happy to help in case of any issues.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#link', function(){
    alert('beep');
});
```

Comment: Bingo. Thanks mate. This makes sense to me now. I can see how the <div> is added dynamically, even though it's already contained in the HTML.

Comment: You dont need event delegation for this just remove .html() while assigning the context. Please check my answer. You are binding to the document which is not at all necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

You can mannuly use popover:

html

```
<div id="popover-wrapper">
  <button id="trigger" data-placement="bottom" title="title">Reveal popover</button>
  <div class="popover right popup-area popover-pos">
    <div class="popover-content">
      <div id="popover-content">
        <a id="link" href="#">click</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#popover-wrapper {
  .popover {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    width: 250px;
    top: 35px;

    .popover-content {
      // ..
    }
  }

  &.open .popover {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

js

```
  $('#trigger').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).delay(250).queue(function(next){
      $(this).addClass('open');
      next();
    });
  }, function() {
      $(this).stop(true, true).delay(250).queue(function(next){
        $(this).removeClass('open');
        next();
      });
    }
  );
```